# For if Loop ManyToMany Field Django

Tags: python, django

> How can I query a manytomanyfield in a Django template? For example,
> this if statement doesn't work, but this shows what I'd like to do:

```
Model:
class Product(models.Model):

    Category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


Template:

{% for p in Product %}
      {% if p.Category_id == 6 %}
             
         {{p.id}}

       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to filter your queryset in `views.py` as

```
products = Product.objects.filter(Category__id=6)
```

then loop through that queryset in **template**

```
{% for p in products %}
         {{p.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual use case. You haven't posted the `view`. Assuming in django template `products` is the queryset. e.g `products= Product.objects.all()`. This is how you will detect the `Category` instance with `id=6` for all the products in django template.

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% for category in p.Category.all %}
        {% if category.id == 6 %}
             {{p.id}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```